# SEO issue: Use ASHX in the src of script tag

Tags: javascript, seo

If I called an ashx page as the src for a script tag and it outputs all the values and a document.write of the contents. Would this been seen by the robots or would this text not get picked up at all since its in a script tag?

For example,

```
<script src="sitemenu.ashx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

SEO is one of the requirements of the project and so I wanna ask if this is okay to have my site menu in the .ashx file.

Thank you.

Comment: You usually do not want **any** file extensions in your website's URLs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the ASHX, it's document.write.

Dynamically client-side built documents do not get indexed by the major search engines.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better +1